# Why is matrix subtraction much slower than dot product in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say we have a vector and a matrix:

```
X = np.random.random((1, 384)).astype('float32')
Y = np.random.random((500000, 384)).astype('float32')
```

Why is `np.dot(X, Y.T)` much faster than `X - Y`?

```
In [8]: %timeit np.dot(X, Y.T)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.4 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit X - Y
1 loop, best of 3: 501 ms per loop
```

What can I do to make subtraction like this as faster as dot product?

Comment: subtraction of matrix when the dimensions are different?

Comment: numpy broadcasting for subtraction may result in more time

Comment: @lamandy Yes, the shape is different, this is one of the step of calculating the manhattan distances.

Comment: @skrubber Yes, do you think this is due to implementation? Or is it impossible to do the subtraction as fast as dot product in theory?

Comment: `np.dot` will usually call a BLAS routine for matrix multiplication if the input arrays are floats. These are usually heavily optimized and possibly multithreaded, depending on which BLAS library your version of numpy is linked against. `np.subtract` is always single threaded.

Answer (score 4):

The size of the output matters, because the output has to be written to memory, and writing a large array takes time. The shape of `dot(X, Y.T)`  is (1, 500000). The shape of X-Y is (500000, 384).

In my test, most of the time taken by X-Y was allocating an array for the output. Compare:

```
%timeit X - Y   
1 loop, best of 3: 449 ms per loop
```

with pre-allocated space `Z = np.zeros_like(Y)`,

```
%timeit np.subtract(X, Y, out=Z)
10 loops, best of 3: 181 ms per loop
```

So, if you have to do this kind of subtraction repeatedly, having a pre-allocated array of suitable shape and type will save more than half of the execution time.

I don't think that subtraction in your case can be made as fast as multiplication. The amount of arithmetics to do is about the same: each entry of X meets 500000 entries of Y either way. The fact that the results are combined when you do multiplication (the summation step) only helps, as the CPU does it quickly with the numbers it already has lying around, and as a result it has only one number to send back. So: about the same amount of work, but the amount of memory-writing is 384 times more for the case of subtraction.

Here is a proof that subtraction **is** faster when the output size is the same for both (square matrices):

```
X = np.random.random((1000, 1000)).astype('float32')
Y = np.random.random((1000, 1000)).astype('float32')

%timeit np.dot(X, Y.T)
100 loops, best of 3: 28.7 ms per loop

%timeit X - Y
1000 loops, best of 3: 579 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a comment, although you already have checked.

I tested whether the broadcast is a cause, but it was not related to performance at all in this case.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: X = np.random.random((1, 384)).astype('float32')
   ...: Y = np.random.random((500000, 384)).astype('float32')

In [3]: %timeit np.dot(X, Y.T)
   ...: %timeit X - Y
27.4 ms ± 910 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
324 ms ± 16.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [4]: import numpy.matlib
   ...: X = np.matlib.repmat(X, 500000, 1)
   ...: print(X.shape)
   ...: %timeit X - Y
(500000, 384)
351 ms ± 20.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Please forgive me I'm not sure how to improve this performance.

Answer (score -1):

Using the np.subtract(X,Y) almost halves the execution time. It is faster than X-Y but the speed is till lower than the dot product. Might help[image]

Comment: It's better to write your code directly, not screen shot.

Comment: I believe np.subtract is more or less the same as subtracting directly. It won't be much faster.